vscode (1.92.0) pytest feature fail to install
vscode 1.92.0 to work with project on WSL2 ubuntu22.04.
When open project in devcontainer, or rebuild devcontainer, the pytest feature fails to install.
Here is the devcontainer.json file:
{
"name": "template-fastapi-mongodb-backend",
"dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
"workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
"service": "app",   
"features": {
    "ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/git:1": {},
    "ghcr.io/hspaans/devcontainer-features/pytest:1": {}
},
"forwardPorts": [
    8000,
    27017
],
"remoteUser": "root",
"containerEnv": {
    "ftp_proxy": "...",
    "https_proxy": "...",
    "http_proxy": "..."
},
"postCreateCommand": "pip install -r requirements.txt"

}
Here is the error message from vscode when open the project in devcontainer:
    [8354 ms] Start: Run: docker compose --project-name template-fastapi-mongodb-backend_devcontainer -f /root/workspace/npa/template-fastapi-mongodb-backend/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml -f /tmp/devcontainercli-root/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1723398542177.yml build
[+] Building 301.4s (15/15) FINISHED                             docker:default
 => [app internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 3.51kB                                     0.0s
 => [app] resolve image config for docker-image://docker.io/docker/docker  1.3s
 => CACHED [app] docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1.4@sha256:9b  0.0s
 => [app internal] load .dockerignore                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [app internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/pyth  0.0s
 => [app context dev_containers_feature_content_source] load .dockerignor  0.0s
 => => transferring dev_containers_feature_content_source: 2B              0.0s
 => [app dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 1/1] FROM mcr.microsoft.com  0.0s
 => [app context dev_containers_feature_content_source] load from client   0.0s
 => => transferring dev_containers_feature_content_source: 18.83kB         0.0s
 => CACHED [app dev_containers_target_stage 1/5] RUN mkdir -p /tmp/dev-co  0.0s
 => CACHED [app dev_containers_feature_content_normalize 1/2] COPY --from  0.0s
 => CACHED [app dev_containers_feature_content_normalize 2/2] RUN chmod -  0.0s
 => CACHED [app dev_containers_target_stage 2/5] COPY --from=dev_containe  0.0s
 => CACHED [app dev_containers_target_stage 3/5] RUN echo "_CONTAINER_USE  0.0s
 => CACHED [app dev_containers_target_stage 4/5] RUN --mount=type=bind,fr  0.0s
 => ERROR [app dev_containers_target_stage 5/5] RUN --mount=type=bind,f  299.8s
------                                                                          
 > [app dev_containers_target_stage 5/5] RUN --mount=type=bind,from=dev_containers_feature_content_source,source=pytest_1,target=/tmp/build-features-src/pytest_1     cp -ar /tmp/build-features-src/pytest_1 /tmp/dev-container-features  && chmod -R 0755 /tmp/dev-container-features/pytest_1  && cd /tmp/dev-container-features/pytest_1  && chmod +x ./devcontainer-features-install.sh  && ./devcontainer-features-install.sh  && rm -rf /tmp/dev-container-features/pytest_1:
0.363 ===========================================================================
0.363 Feature       : Pytest (via pipx)
0.363 Description   : The pytest framework makes it easy to write small tests, yet scales to support complex functional testing for applications and libraries.
0.363 Id            : ghcr.io/hspaans/devcontainer-features/pytest
0.363 Version       : 1.0.3
0.363 Documentation : http://github.com/hspaans/devcontainer-features/tree/master/src/pytest
0.363 Options       :
0.363     VERSION="latest"
0.363     PLUGINS=""
0.363 ===========================================================================
299.7 ERROR: Feature "Pytest (via pipx)" (ghcr.io/hspaans/devcontainer-features/pytest) failed to install! Look at the documentation at http://github.com/hspaans/devcontainer-features/tree/master/src/pytest for help troubleshooting this error.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cp -ar /tmp/build-features-src/pytest_1 /tmp/dev-container-features  && chmod -R 0755 /tmp/dev-container-features/pytest_1  && cd /tmp/dev-container-features/pytest_1  && chmod +x ./devcontainer-features-install.sh  && ./devcontainer-features-install.sh  && rm -rf /tmp/dev-container-features/pytest_1" did not complete successfully: exit code: 28
[309962 ms] Error: Command failed: docker compose --project-name template-fastapi-mongodb-backend_devcontainer -f /root/workspace/npa/template-fastapi-mongodb-backend/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml -f /tmp/devcontainercli-root/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1723398542177.yml build
[309962 ms]     at Km (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:430:525)
[309963 ms]     at async QtA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:430:2476)
[309963 ms]     at async utA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:410:3506)
[309963 ms]     at async KtA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:482:3944)
[309963 ms]     at async eB (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:482:4886)
[309964 ms]     at async hrA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:663:200)
[309964 ms]     at async lrA (/root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:662:13452)
[309971 ms] Exit code 1
[310002 ms] Command failed: /root/.vscode-server/bin/b1c0a14de1414fcdaa400695b4db1c0799bc3124/node /root/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-1ae8d3f6-00c5-470d-860b-01d0473a00371723398533061 --workspace-folder /root/workspace/npa/template-fastapi-mongodb-backend --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=\\wsl$\Ubuntu-22.04\root\workspace\npa\template-fastapi-mongodb-backend --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/root/workspace/npa/template-fastapi-mongodb-backend/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /root/workspace/npa/template-fastapi-mongodb-backend/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root --include-configuration --include-merged-configuration
[310002 ms] Exit code 1

This same devcontainer.json works fine with vscode 1.91.1. It also works fine in vscode 1.92.0 by removing the pytest feature from the devcontainer.json.
My question is, how can I have this feature installed when the project is opened in devcontainer?
Thanks
